# Cannot strip integer from string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, byte

I have a list of two strings, and I cannot convert a string into a integer.
Given the formatting of the string, I assume there is some stuff happening in the background that I cannot decipher.

**MWE:**

```
for tag_details_list in tag_details_list_of_lists:
    tag = tag_details_list[0].split(":")[1].strip()
    download_size = tag_details_list[1].split(":")[1].split(" ")[-2]
    t2 = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', tag_details_list[0].split(":")[1].strip())
    ds2 = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', tag_details_list[1].split(":")[1].split(" ")[-2])
    print(tag, download_size)
    print(type(tag), type(download_size)) 
    print("- - "*8)
    print(t2, ds2[0])
    print(type(t2), type(ds2[0]))
    print("----"*8)
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

[image]

**QUESTION:**

How can I convert the highlighted strings into integer?

**ADDENDUM: 1**

Print out of the `tag_details_list_of_lists` var

```
[['    - itag:          \x1b[7m399\x1b[0m', '      size:          18.0 MiB (18902495 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m137\x1b[0m', '      size:          13.0 MiB (13648409 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m398\x1b[0m', '      size:          12.5 MiB (13140162 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m397\x1b[0m', '      size:          8.9 MiB (9362043 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m136\x1b[0m', '      size:          7.3 MiB (7674797 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m396\x1b[0m', '      size:          7.3 MiB (7614162 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m135\x1b[0m', '      size:          6.3 MiB (6589599 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m395\x1b[0m', '      size:          6.0 MiB (6274426 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m134\x1b[0m', '      size:          5.8 MiB (6099424 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m394\x1b[0m', '      size:          5.5 MiB (5720386 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m133\x1b[0m', '      size:          5.2 MiB (5459770 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m160\x1b[0m', '      size:          4.8 MiB (5083948 bytes)'], ['    - itag:          \x1b[7m18\x1b[0m', '      size:          9.2 MiB (9654186 bytes)']
```

Comment: Could you use a regex r'\d+' to extract only digits first?

Comment: How about `int(tag)`?

Comment: Can you provide (an example of) the input data?

Comment: @JonSG pls see Addendum 1